# How to unit test a simple class?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python class:

```
class Animal:
   def __init__(self, name, energy=100):
       self.name = name
       self.energy = energy
```

I need to create some simple tests using module unittest. For example, to test if energy is greater than zero or
name is a string type. How should i do it? (i have no experience yet).

Comment: Those don't sound like reasonable unit tests for this code. They might be reasonable unit tests for other code, but not this code.

Comment: https://pythontesting.net/framework/unittest/unittest-introduction/

Comment: You can read this. Very simple and sraight forward -  <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unit-testing-python-unittest/>

Comment: For example, you can't unit test that `name` is a string, because `name` doesn't come from this code at all.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica he may test the default value for energy

Answer (score 7):

These kinds of things wouldn't normally be tested with a unit test, but instead they would be enforced with a [class invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant) in the `__init__` method:

```
# animal.py

class Animal:
   def __init__(self, name, energy=100):
       if not isinstance(name, str):
           raise TypeError("name should be a string")
       if energy <= 0:
           raise ValueError("energy has to be more than 0")

       self.name = name
       self.energy = energy
```

This way you can never even accidentally create an `Animal` with invalid values in it.

Of course, after setting those invariants, you *can* test that they are actually in place. For example with the popular [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) module:

```
import pytest

from animal import Animal


def test_init_ok():
    animal = Animal("name", 100)
    assert animal.name == "name"
    assert animal.energy == 100


def test_init_bad_name():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        animal = Animal(123, 100)


def test_init_bad_energy():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        animal = Animal("name", 0)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        animal = Animal("name", -100)
```

Or by using the built-in [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module:

```
import unittest

from animal import Animal


class AnimalTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_init_ok(self):
        animal = Animal("name", 100)
        self.assertEqual(animal.name, "name")
        self.assertEqual(animal.energy, 100)

    def test_init_bad_name(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            animal = Animal(123, 100)

    def test_init_bad_energy(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            animal = Animal("name", 0)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            animal = Animal("name", -100)
```